# [jquery-1.4] but [jquery1.5] on SO

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I found some heterogeneity among jQuery tags on SO:

[jquery-1.3](/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3), [jquery-1.4](/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4) but [jquery1.5](/questions/tagged/jquery1.5)

Is it possible to rename [jquery1.5](/questions/tagged/jquery1.5) to [jquery-1.5](/questions/tagged/jquery-1.5) and add the first as the synonym to the second?

Comment: [Already done](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/598592#598592)

Comment: @Yi: Thanks! Could you or Nick post an answer please so I could accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [jquery-1.5](/questions/tagged/jquery-1.5) tag is now correct, with a synonym from [jquery1.5](/questions/tagged/jquery1.5) pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

[**Already done! \o/**](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/598592#598592)

<sup>I can't think of anything else witty to say.</sup>

Comment: You should totally drop [jquery1.5] and use [jquery-1.5] instead